# Gap between Routes Management in Production & Dev?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have defined the following actions in route file.

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

GET     /abc                        controllers.Application.abc()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

When i run Play in dev mode (play run) it returns "Action Not Found" error when browsing /abc while it works well in prod mode (play start)

I have clean all target resources, recompile, clean, clean all ... but it is still the same behaviour

Does someone know what the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: It's at least weird ...

Comment: Sounds very strange, are you doing anything special in your app, can you share the project?